# Can't select UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm making an iPad app. In the app I have multiple UITextViews. I've already made it possible to scroll to the specific UITextView. Now the problem:

The app always scrolls to the UITextView which is made last. I know I can select the UITextView with the tag (example: [self.view viewWithTag:1]). But I don't have a tag.

Edit:
I see that the variable is pointing to the wrong object. That can be changed by the viewWithTag function. But then I need to know the tag for the active TextView.

Is there a way to get the active textView like in activetextfield?

I hope anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a tag works, why don't you assign a tag to these views?

If you're creating the views programatically, then assign a tag on creation.

If you're creating the views via a NIB, you can assign tags via UIBuilder.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I know I can create tags. As you already sayd I create them programatically. In a loop i create the UITextViews and assign the Tags.

But how do I know wich TextView.tag I selected?

Comment: OK, in the responder that handles the event, can you not just read the tag property? So, textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView passes you the textView, and textView.tag gives you the associated tag.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks Snips! Didn't think of that. Gonna try it out!

Comment: Cool, glad that helped you out.

Comment: It worked. I had to add de UITextViewDelegate. And trough there i could use the textViewDidBeginEditing() function.